# Question asked on Stack Overflow has gone into the ether

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions

I was using **[-edit with browser-]** and tried to post a question about **[-edit with question topic (could help)-]** on Stack Overflow.

Now, I can't find it anywhere and it's not linked on my profile. Can anyone help a brutha out?

Comment: then what is this?

Comment: Fill out the blanks!

Comment: @random: nice "edit" :D. makes the OP look a less, hm.. inexperienced!

Comment: @random How do you even know it's a male?

Answer (score 3):

Was it one of these?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/215282/geri

Answer (score 1):

Geri, something went wrong the first time. Please try again (with your real question, that is). Not here at 'Meta', but at [SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Good luck!